# How to to pass a date to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, between

I have the following SP:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Assignments] 
                WHERE ProjectId=@ProjectUID AND TaskId=@TaskUID AND ResourceId=@ResourceUID
                AND (StartDate <= @DATE AND FinishDate >= @DATE)
            )
BEGIN
        Return  1

END
ELSE
BEGIN
        Return 2
END
```

When I executed it with some parameters, it's returns me 2(I have taken this parameter for my date `@Date = '2018-11-02'`) so I decided to try in select statement, and the select statement return me a line and if I put my Line with start and end date in comments, my SP works
So I know that my trouble is coming from the date
But I don't understand why

PS: I have already tried with a between but the result is the same

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your table? and expect result thanks

Comment: Need to cast startdate and enddate into date. if @date param is string then also need to cast into date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare dates using the date parts of `datetime` columns:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[Assignments] 
    WHERE 
        ProjectId = @ProjectUID AND 
        TaskId = @TaskUID AND 
        ResourceId = @ResourceUID AND 
        (CONVERT(date, StartDate) <= @DATE AND CONVERT(date, FinishDate) >= @DATE)
)
BEGIN
    Return  1
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    Return 2
END
```

Comment: It's weird
I did a cast with the between but it didn't work, I added it with the compar signs and now it's working
Thanks